# How to describe a strong wind?

Tags: expressions

Could you say 'The gale was blowing about his jacket' ? I'd like to express the repetitive movement of his jacket going from side to side.

Comment: Do you want to describe the "strong wind" or the "motion of his jacket"? For the wind, you can look into "gust" (noun), "blustery" (adjective), or their synonyms.

Comment: There are a dozen different words for wind, and even a song or two.  As to the flutter of the jacket, I can't think of a single word to describe that.

Comment: The jacket flapping in the strong wind.

Comment: swing, bounce, rock, sway, vibrate, flutter, wobble, oscillate, shake, wave, whip, be battered, flap, be agitated.

Comment: saying the gale was blowing about the jacket makes it sound like the gale is smaller than the jacket. "The Gale was blowing his jacket about" avoids this wrinkle.

Comment: From the answers I like `whipping` over `flapping`. Since we are talking about a gale here `flapping` seems not strong enough. That would be something for 4-7 bft.

Comment: The key here is: do you want to describe the gale or the jacket? Different subjects draw the reader's attention to different places.

Comment: Precisely, and thank you @ssdecontrol, as I type the top answer is "flapping" which may describe "the jacket" but cannot be said to describe "the wind", whereas the thrust of the OP (entitled: How to describe a strong wind?) seeks a description of "the gale". Please clarify.

Comment: ELU is not a writing suggestion service. Look up synonyms of 'gale' or 'wind'. Then ask what are the nuances of meaning are. Then you yourself need to judge what is appropriate for your personal writing needs.

Answer (score 14):

***[Whipping](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whip)*** could be used metaphorically, to describe both the wind and the jacket:

> 2.0 Move fast or suddenly in a specified direction:

In the continuous form, the word picture of "quick motion" is ongoing, evoking the image of a literal whip being drawn back and struck forward repetitively.

It applies to the jacket metaphorically as it moves back and forth, and applies to the wind as the cause of the jackets whipping motion.

Comment: +1.  Whipping implies a strength of motion more commensurate with a gale than does flapping.

Answer (score 7):

I'd go with **His coat was flapping in the wind.**

Answer (score 6):

> **Buffeting**:
>
> **1**. the action of striking someone or something repeatedly and violently.
> see google.com, “buffeting” [Link](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=buffeting+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

• **"His nylon jacket was repeatedly buffeted by the howling gale"**

> **Buffet** *verb*:
> **1**. (***especially of wind or waves***) strike repeatedly and violently; batter. *Synonyms*: batter, pound, lash, strike, hit; see google.com, “buffet” [Link](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=buffet+definition&gws_rd=ssl)

• **"rough ocean winds *buffeted* their jackets"**

Comment: Doesn't shredded have a much stronger meaning? His jacket isn't in pieces, it's just fiercely blown by the wind.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe battered? "The wind battered at his jacket". I assume he's wearing the jacket, not that it's hoisted into the air from the ground or a clothesline.

Answer (score 1):

His jacket fluttered in the fierce gale.

Comment: That seems rather odd. Fluttering is much too light and feeble a movement to fit a fierce gale. His jacket may well flutter in the breeze, but in a full-on gale, it would be more likely to billow, flap, flail, or even thrash or beat around him.

Answer (score 1):

How about these?

```
His jacket was fluttering as a gust of wind blew past us.
```

or

```
His jacket flapped about as a gust of wind blew past.
```

*flap* is defined as : *a movement of a wing or an arm from side to side or up and down.* But I suppose it could be used for describing the jacket's motion here.

or

```
Hi jacket beat against him as a gust of wind blew past.
```

Comment: fluttering is what springs to mind.+1

Comment: Flutter describes a light movement, probably not matching that caused by a *strong* wind.

Answer (score 0):

Howling ceaselessly, the wind fluttered through his flying jacket, as the man attempted in vain to muffle the tempest beneath his nylon clothing.

Answer (score 0):

[The official Beaufort wind scale](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/guides/coast-and-sea/beaufort-scale) may be helpful as it provides descriptions of each force level.